# Best way to handle multiple types of an entity in database

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a course entity that can be online or offline and has lessons. Depending on the type, the lesson can have two sets of fields. Datetimes for online courses and sections for offline courses that contain video files and some extra attributes such as 'is_watched' and etc. If we create a Fields table that has keys and values for each lesson, if the course is online those extra attributes for offline courses would have to be null. And if we create both tables for each type of course, we have to define two relations that one of them does not exist, and also we have to check for the type every time we are accessing the fields.
What is the best way to implement these tables and their relations? And how to access those fields based on the type?

Answer (score 0):

you might need to check polymorphic relations in laravel
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

you could create two tables online/offline courses
the lesson model will have one method "call it courses"
the polymorphic relation will create two columns in lessons table
courseable_id   --->id of either table
courseable_id   --> name space of either model ex  App\Models\OnlineCources or App\Models\OfflineCources